# Failure to run Android Studio in Mac m1 environment prompts unexpected exit. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: macos, android-studio

When I ran Android studio on m1 mac, there was a crash and I could not run Android studio properly. I went to the MacOs directory of package content to execute the studio file and got the running log as follows, which indicates that the dmg I installed is not arm architecture. But I can confirm that dmg is installed for arm architecture. If you have any trouble to help me solve it, thank you very much

2023-05-26 20:22:44.809 studio[4597:53107] Cannot load JVM bundle: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3585 "dlopen_preflight(/Volumes/Android Studio - Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib) => false, tried: '/Volumes/Android Studio - Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Volumes/Android Studio - Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib' (no such file), '/Volumes/Android Studio - Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try installing a universal version of the bundle., NSFilePath=/Volumes/Android Studio - Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Volumes/Android Studio - Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib) => false, tried: '/Volumes/Android Studio - Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Volumes/Android Studio - Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib' (no such file), '/Volumes/Android Studio - Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), NSBundlePath=/Volumes/Android Studio - Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “OpenJDK 17.0.6” couldn’t be loaded because it doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture.}

Once you have exited Android studio and re-opened it, the problem will exit unexpectedly. It can only be rectified after a restart. It won't open in the back, and the reboot won't work. I tried to upgrade to the latest stable version of Android studio and still had this problem. Rebooting won't solve the problem

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the correct 64-bit ARM architecture for an M1 mac? Sounds like you got the Mac 64-Bit (which is for Intel processors).  Scroll down [the android studio download page](https://developer.android.com/studio/) and find the android-studio-2022.2.1.20-mac_arm.dmg one. (or the current version at the time).

Comment: Yes, I confirmed that the download is 64-bit arm architecture dmg

Comment: @tianfumeng The error says itself that the app is not ```arm``` compatible : ```(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')```

Comment: "I went to the MacOs directory of package content to execute the studio file" why? Why don't you just double tap the thing?  And like the previous comment, are you sure this is an ARM mac? It's weird that it says "needs X86_64" as if it's trying to run under Rosetta2 or similar?

Comment: Because double-clicking can't open under normal circumstances, I went to the macos directory to execute it so that I can see what it is.

Comment: Dmg must be the arm architecture. I have carefully checked it many times. I also wonder why such a problem occurs.

Comment: If you download `android-studio-2022.2.1.20-mac_arm.dmg`, and double-click it, Finder should open with the Android Studio icon, and an "arrow" to drag it to Applications (which is located in `/Applications`). From there on, you should have, inside Applications, an icon called Android Studio. Double clicking that macOS package should launch the binary. Anything else is extremely puzzling. Does your machine have corporate restrictions or similar? Are you an admin? (shouldn't be needed) Are you absolutely sure you have an M1 Mac? What's the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Darwin mengtianfudeMacBook-Pro.local 22.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.3.0: Thu Jan  5 20:48:54 PST 2023; root:xnu-8792.81.2~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 x86_64

Comment: Drag it to the application directory and double-click the icon to open it.  It doesn't work properly.  There was an unexpected exit prompt, so I went to the macOs directory in the contents of the AndroidStudio package and opened it so I could see the startup log

Comment: ok, my work-supplied machine is a macbook pro M1. My `uname -a` ends with `/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64`, and yours end with `/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 x86_64`. I haven't really used much macOS in a long time outside of this work machine as it's not my OS of choice, so I can't tell you much but it seems like somehow you're running an Intel machine? I'm sure you know you're on an M1 but I don't know why an M1 machine would report `x86_64`. Puzzling. Did you try "just for fun" to run the Intel version? (I'm curious)

Comment: What's the output of the command: `arch` and `uname -p`? Seems like somehow you're running the Terminal with Rosetta. Not sure how to be honest, as I haven't really tweaked and used macOS since Snow Leopard (and now this Ventura abomination). Check [this AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420452/running-uname-m-gives-x86-64-on-m1-mac-mini) post, to see if you can change it to not run under Rosetta (it's explained there).

Comment: arch and uname -p output i386, which means Intel is running? I wonder why that is

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The problem is that the terminal is run by Rosetta. I've turned this option on before. Now I can't open Android Studio by double clicking on the icon after shutting it down, and I still have an unexpected exit.

I tried to go to the macOs directory in the as package contents to run the studio file, and the error log appeared roughly as follows: I will send the log in batches below. Your valuable opinion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Since the log is too long, could you please provide me with an email address to send the log to you? Hope to get your valuable advice and guidance, thank you very much for your help